# Extjs Using actioncolumn to make radiocolumn not working

Tags: extjs, grid, radio-button, extjs4.1

I try to make a radio column using actioncolumn in **http://jsfiddle.net/WAZah/**

here is my items in actioncolum

```
             items: [{              
                 icon:'',
                 //renderer: function (val, metadata, record) {
                 getClass: function(value,metadata,record){
                     //alert(record.get('check'));
                     var knowledge = record.get('check');
                     if (knowledge == 1 ){                                      
                        return 'radio-col-on';
                         //metadata.css = 'radio-col-on'
                     } else {  
                         return 'radio-col-off';
                         //metadata.css = 'radio-col-off'
                     }               
                 }  
             }]
```

and my css

```
.x-action-col-cell img.radio-col-on {
    background-image: url('http://compare-gap-insurance.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Vista_radio-button_general1.jpg') !important;   
}
.x-action-col-cell img.radio-col-off {
    background-image: url('http://www.uams.edu/safety/images/Radio-button.jpg') !important;   
}
```

How can i make that work thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a regular column with a renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a css class name which gets applied to the image, but you have no image (or at least not one that's rendered large enough to see).  If you add an icon image such as a transparent spacer gif of the same size as your radio button image, this should work.

I suggest that you might want to use the suggestion from @Reimius though.  You could actually create a real radio button in the cell if you use a regular column and a renderer.

At any rate, here's code that seems to work for your example:

```
items: [{              
    icon:'/url/path/to/a/transparent/spacer.gif',
    getClass: function(value,metadata,record){
        var knowledge = record.get('check');
        if (knowledge == 1 ){                                      
            return 'radio-col-on';
        } else {  
            return 'radio-col-off';
        }               
    }
}]
```

And a fiddle that updates your example to use this technique with a (admittedly incorrectly sized) spacer gif: http://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/WAZah/3/

Comment: Add height:16px; to your css class instead of the spacer : http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/WAZah/4/

Comment: @dbrin Ah, yeah, that's a much better solution than the spacer image.

Comment: thank u, Can u give me a link or example for your suggestion :)

Comment: He did.  It's the fiddle link in his comment.  It's basically your original code with the addition of the css height settings for your actioncolumn classes.  Oh, do you mean the "real radio button" suggestion?  That's a little more involved and involves deferring addition of a component into a custom div you create in a column renderer function.  On further reflection, this version looks pretty good as it is already.  :)  You might want to get radio button png images with a transparent background, though, since the white background shows up on your gray rows and looks a little incomplete.